# Openlayers map scale line same zoom rate repeated twice in metric even-though the zoom differs

Tags: javascript, typescript, zooming, openlayers

Openlayers Map scale line in Metric unit has a particular zoom rate repeated twice on zoom eventhough the actually zoom-in resolution differs in map.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/scale-line.html  As you can see in the link the zoom rates 5km and 5m are repeated twice for two different zoom levels

How i declared my zoom rates  in view.

```
var viewLayer = new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 10,
            minZoom: 15,
            maxZoom: 24,
            resolution: 0.2,
            minResolution: 0.0125,
            maxResolution: 6.4
        });
```

Scale line control declaration as

```
var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
            minWidth: 100,
            units: 'metric'
        });
```

With the above declaration ranging from 1000m to 1m - 5m is repeated twice in metric unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicates you must use a resolutions array to match the scale line intervals

The scale line intervals are fixed like this

```
5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1
```

If you don't use a resolutions array OpenLayers fixes the rsolutions at even intervals between the min and max, for example

```
4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
```

so (in that case) you would have two resolutions which fit between 2000 and 5000 on the scale line

Comment: Tried giving like this 
var viewLayer = new ol.View
    ({
      resolutions : [6.4, 3.2, 1.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.025, 0.0125],
      center: [0, 0],
      ....
   });      But no luck, still the 5m zoom level is repeated twice. Im using openlayers-3.15.1

Comment: On the equator 100 pixels at resolution 0.0125 is 1.25 meters so the scale line will extent to the next step which 2 meters.  So you need to set the resolutions for `1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2` meters which will be `[ 6.25, 3.125, 1.25, 0.625, 0.3125, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.0125 ]`

Comment: In web mercator projection if you pan away from the equator the true scale won't match the resolution so it won't work in all locations.

Comment: Hi Mike, with your resolutions 
`var view = new ol.View
    ({
      resolutions : [ 6.25, 3.125, 1.25, 0.625, 0.3125, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 
 0.0125 ],
   ...
      minResolution: 0.0125,
      maxResolution: 6.25
    });`   this set of resolutions solved my Problem in metric unit(meters) . But the Imperial unit (feet) which was working fine before is collapsed now. It comes up repeated 50 ft zoom rates

Comment: What works for one unit wont work for another.  The first step above 1.25 meters (4.1 feet) is 5 feet.  
So the scaleline intervals will be `2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5` feet which will need matching resolutions of `[ 5, 2.5, 1.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.05, 0.025, 0.0125 ]`

Comment: is there any generic way for giving resolutions such that it works fine for whatever unit system i use like E,g: meter or feet ? or any parameter i can add to make this generic

Comment: `minWidth * minResolution` gives you the smallest possible scaleline length in meters, which needs rounding up after converting to scaleline units to fit the intervals of the scaleline you will be using.  Metric always goes in steps of 1, 2, 5, 10, etc.  Imperial will be harder as the units also change between inches, feet and miles.  5, 10, 20 inches, then 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000 feet, then 2, 5, 10, etc. miles

Answer (score 0):

You can give resolutions array to your [view](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html). Note that, as said in the documentation :

> If set the maxResolution, minResolution, minZoom, maxZoom, and
>   zoomFactor options are ignored

But this is not really clean since you will need to give resolutions with large step in order to avoid scaleline values to be the same on zoom.

Actually this is intended to work like this for readability reasons. Values are the same but scale line width isn't, so it's not really a probleme right ?

Also a mix between resolutions passed to the view and minWidth for the scaleline should do the job, but again, it will be just home made hacks, theis is no kind of parameters in OpenLayers-5 to achieve exactly what you want to do !

Comment: The scale line width changing is not a problem. Even without the minWidth parameter in scaleLineControl the repeated zoom rate issue occurs.